# Fancy two-column table from scratch

Tags: tables

I tried making my own customized two-column table, but got stuck:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\title {table}{Fancy two-column table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Names}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Numbers}}\\\hline
entry & item
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Frankly, I'm not sure this approach I started would produce a fancy-looking classical two column table, as I'm looking to maybe make the column headers a little more elegant.  I'm looking to produce something like:

[image]

where the "Fancy Header A" and "Fancy Header B" can be very fancy or just a little bit more fancy than the rest of the entries in the table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a *very fancy table*, consider using `booktabs` and remove the vertical lines.

Then you can apply whatever formatting you want to the first row.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textsf{Names}}}&\textbf{\textsf{Numbers}}\\
\midrule
entry & item\\
entry & item\\
entry & item\\
entry & item\\
entry & item\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]